# year difference in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula

I have two columns of year in excel sheet as year.months format (column first as 1.11 means 1 year 11 months) column second as 0.7 means 7 months). I need difference between two columns as year.months format. i.e., 1.11-0.7=1.4 means 1 year 4 months.

Comment: I would try converting them into dates then using datedif to get the difference then converting them back into numbers. Might try later.

Comment: how is a 12 month difference supposed to be dispalyed?  1.0 or 0.12

Comment: @TomSharpe I was bored at work and typed or my interpretation of your comment as an answer.  Not trying to take credit away from you.  I will delete it if you want.

Comment: No not at all. I was thinking of converting to actual dates but just converting to months is a better idea. The other way is somehow to make them into 1.01, 1.02 ... 1,11 and do some maths on those, but that seemed to work out even longer.

Comment: @TomSharpe my first answer that I had typed up was all math and because I thought the format was numbers and not a string had it working too until I realized you can't distinguish between 1.1 and 1.10 if they are numbers

Answer (score 1):

This approach will perform the math by converting everything to the same base units as month.  You can perform the steps over multiple column which will make it easier to read, maintain and troubleshoot.  When everything is working you can combine it into a single formula which will be a monstrosity that is hard to read and potentially maintain by others in the future.

For the sake of this solution, assume your 1.11 date is in A1 and you 0.7 date is in B1.

Step 1) Convert A1 and B1 to months

In C1 place the following formula and copy it to D1

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1)*12+RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1))
```

Step 2)  Find the difference in months

In E1 Place the following formula

```
=C1-D1
```

Step 3)  Convert difference in months back in to year.month format

In F1 place the following formula

```
=INT(E1/12)&"."&(E1-INT(E1/12)*12)
```

Now if you got and substitute formulas into one another so its all in a single cell, your formula will wind up looking the following.

```
=INT(((LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1)*12+RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1)))-(LEFT(B1,FIND(".",B1)-1)*12+RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-FIND(".",B1))))/12)&"."&(((LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1)*12+RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1)))-(LEFT(B1,FIND(".",B1)-1)*12+RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-FIND(".",B1))))-INT(((LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1)*12+RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1)))-(LEFT(B1,FIND(".",B1)-1)*12+RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-FIND(".",B1))))/12)*12)
```

I would not want to be someone new coming in and looking at that and trying to figure out what its doing let alone editing it 3 months down the road when a change is required.

[image: POC]

A few caveats,  Make sure the date in A is bigger than the date in B.  It gives bad results for negative values.  Also ensure there is always a "." in the date or errors will ensue.  If there is a 12 month difference it will currently display 1.0 as the difference instead of 0.12.  If the later is required, a special case would need to be developed for when there is differences resulting in multiples of 12 differences.

Answer (score 1):

Working with DatedIF

Assume start date is in B1 and end date is in A1.

Step 1)  Convert date

Convert the string to an actual excel serial date

In C1 and Use the following formula and copy to D1

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1)),1)
```

The conversion assumes the first of the month

Step 2)  Determine the difference in months

Place the following in E1

```
=DATEDIF(D1,C1,"M")
```

Note the start date need to be further back in time than the end date or you will get #NUM error.

Step 3)  Convert back to your string format for y.m

Place the following in F1

```
=INT(E1/12)&"."&(E1-INT(E1/12)*12)
```

and combined into the uglyness of a single cell formula:

```
=INT((DATEDIF(DATE(LEFT(B1,FIND(".",B1)-1),RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-FIND(".",B1)),1),DATE(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1)),1),"M"))/12)&"."&((DATEDIF(DATE(LEFT(B1,FIND(".",B1)-1),RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-FIND(".",B1)),1),DATE(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1)),1),"M"))-INT((DATEDIF(DATE(LEFT(B1,FIND(".",B1)-1),RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-FIND(".",B1)),1),DATE(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1)),1),"M"))/12)*12)
```

Comment: This is basically Tom Shape's comment

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `A1=1.11` and `B1=0.7` then formula would be:

`=LEFT(A1;FIND(".";A1;1)-1)-LEFT(B1;FIND(".";B1;1)-1)&"."&(MID(A1;FIND(".";A1;1)+1;2)-MID(B1;FIND(".";B1;1)+1;2))`

[image]

Comment: is the dot a decimal separator for you?

Comment: Oh!!!! true, sorry, in my Excel arguments in formulas are separated by `;` instead of `,`

Comment: but 2.00 + 0.00 =#value

Comment: in your question you said *I need difference between two columns*, and `2.00 + 0.00` is a sum, not a difference.

Comment: Anyways. you can update the formula perfectly for your new needs.